# Computed column in POSTGRESQL-Column Derived from a function

Tags: database-migration, ddl, postgresql-11, derived-column

Want to  create a COMPUTED COLUMN in POSTGRESQL which has to be a migration of MSSQLCODE .The computed column is as a result of a function "FUN_GetExternalSystemNameFull"

**MSSQL CODE FOR TABLE**

```
   CREATE TABLE ClientApplication(  
ClientApplicationId bigint    IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
ClientId bigint NULL,
ExternalSystemNameFull  AS    (dbo.FUN_GetExternalSystemNameFull(ClientApplicationId,' | ')),
Age bigint
)
```

function **FUN_GetExternalSystemNameFull** in **POSTGRESQL** :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "FUN_GetExternalSystemNameFull"(v_subscriptionid bigint, v_separator character varying)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
RETURN((SELECT STRING_AGG("c"."ExternalSystemName",coalesce(v_separator,'')) from(select "ExternalSystemName"
      from "ClientApplication"
      where "ApplicationId" = v_subscriptionId) "c"));    
END; $function$
```

Iam not able to create a POSTGRESQL TABLE with  computed column from the function.Please help.
Iam using Postgresql 11

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: The function uses a **generated** value of the (supposedly) primary key of the table and then tries to retrieve multiple values (from the same table) based on that **not yet existing** value in a different column. That function makes no sense to me whatsoever for a generated column